# Deploy Laravel based Project client side

Tags: php, deployment, laravel-4

I made a project in laravel 4.Now I want to deploy it at client's local PC such that the files are not accessible/found in PC.So how can I deploy it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking

Comment: Hi Damien,I want to deploy my project on client pc locally as they don't use internet.Now how to deploy such that code/files is not accessible to them.Just want to create publish type of file.

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible.
But you can encrypt all code with `IONCube`, that way it will be shown but in encrypted form.

Comment: Do in PHP it has option like publish which is available in .NET which creates a single file to be executed.

Comment: I am not aware of either .NET, nor such option in PHP.